How to count messages on kafka without consuming them
Hi I want to learn about how can I check count of messages on kafka through java springboot without consuming them. I just want to count them and allow consumption only when certain number has exceeded. How can I do this ?

https://www.baeldung.com/java-kafka-count-topic-messages

Using the spring-kafka client, you can query the topic's partition offsets. By comparing each partition's earliest and latest offsets, you can determine the approximate number of messages in the topic.

@SamarPrakash It will only be approximate since that includes transaction markers rather than real events, and does not work for compacted topics

Yeah, I understand. That's why I said "approximate number of messages."
